# postgresql UUID equivalent in coldFusion

Tags: postgresql, coldfusion, uuid, postgresql-9.1

I have a table session which is having sess_uuid column of type UUID in postgres , my problem is that I have to update session table from coldFusion cfQuery using query :

```
UPDATE sessions
    SET     sess_frn_usr_id = 1 
    WHERE   sess_uuid = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.SessionToSave.get('sessUuid')#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_other">
```

Problem in this query is that sess_uuid column is of type UUID in database and here in ColdFusion the equivalent type is `cf_sql_other` which is not working for this. The error is:

> ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = character varying

Which cf_sql type in ColdFusion is to be used here to map UUID column in postgres?

Comment: I don't have Postgres installed here to verify, but googling says that people have fixed this issue by updating the JDBC drivers for Postgres.

Comment: can you brief which driver is used to resolve this?

Comment: Most of the posts are old, but were talking about upgrading to 8.3.

Comment: @phantom tested with that too, not at all solving this sucking issue , and it is very urgent for me to solve it out, still thanks to you for helping me in this.

Comment: This is not a great solution in the long term, but you could cast the `uuid` column to `varchar`. Then it would work with a string: `WHERE CAST(sess_uuid  AS varchar) = <cfqueryparam value="(some value)" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">`

Comment: @Leigh this also not working.:(

Comment: @SatishSharma - It worked fine for me with postgresql 9.1 and CF10. (Actually your original code worked fine too) 1) What versions are you running? 2) What is an example of a value that fails?

Comment: QLeigh postgresql 9.1 and CF9.0.2

Comment: And what is the actual value are you passing into cfqueryparam? So I can test the same on my end.

Comment: @Leigh value for cfqueryparam is d0c2b125-9222-d479-fb4a-be912b8c7c3b

Comment: @SatishSharma - Are you *positive* that is the exact code causing the error? It also works fine under CF9.0.0 with a small test table: `create table test (uuidCol uuid, title varchar(100))`. I only get the "operator does not exist..." error when using cf_sql_varchar. Type `cf_sql_other` works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your query with both CF9.0 and 10, against PostgreSQL 9.1, and type `cf_sql_other` worked just fine. So either that is not the actual query causing the error or perhaps something else is going on beyond what we can see. Does your DSN have any special jdbc connection settings?

> ```
>     ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = character varying
> ```
>
> Which cf_sql type in ColdFusion is to be used here to map UUID column
>   in postgres?

Based on my limited tests and [a few quick searches](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-jdbc/2009-03/msg00009.php), `cf_sql_other` is the correct type to use with the PostgreSQL driver bundled in CF9+. There is no straight equivalent for PostgreSQL's `uuid` type in jdbc 3, so type [`OTHER`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#OTHER) is used to indicate it is database-specific, and the driver internals take it from there.

I was only able to reproduce your error by using one of the *string* types, like `cf_sql_varchar` or omitting the `cfsqltype` so it defaults to `cf_sql_char`. Given the error message, direct comparisons between uuid and strings are not supported. You must explicitly cast the uuid to a string first (or vice versa). All of the examples below worked for me with CF9+ and PostgreSQL 9.1.

```
  <!--- uuid = "d0c2b125-9222-d479-fb4a-be912b8c7c3b" --->
  <!--- syntax 1 ---->
  WHERE   CAST(sess_uuid AS VARCHAR)  = <cfqueryparam value="#uuid#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">   

  <!--- syntax 2 ---->
  WHERE   sess_uuid::text  = <cfqueryparam value="#uuid#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">   

  <!--- syntax 3 --->
  WHERE   sess_uuid  = <cfqueryparam value="#uuid#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">::uuid
```

Though I would not recommend it, it is worth noting that omitting cfqueryparam also works.  Since a direct comparison with a `varchar` value fails (even in postgresql) I guess there is some extra conversion magic happening in this one case.

```
  <!--- fails --->
  WHERE   sess_uuid = CAST('#uuid#' AS VARCHAR)

  <!--- works --->
  WHERE   sess_uuid = '#uuid#'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you qualify what you mean by "not working"? Is it errorring with a validation error? Can you please update your question to include that info.

Does `CF_SQL_IDSTAMP` not work?

If not, there's not much you can do. you could either not type-check it at all (the `cfsqltype` is not a *required* parameter of `<cfqueryparam>`), or for the sake of completeness just treat it as a `CF_SQL_VARCHAR` and length-check it too.

Comment: not working means throwing exception ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = character and CF_SQL_IDSTAMP is not of any use here

Comment: What does "which is stucked problem" mean?